# Getting an 1054 Error with new EE Twitter Plugin

Tags: ee2, error, twitter

I recently added the [EE Twitter Plug](https://github.com/click-rain/EE_Twitter) found on github to replace the Twitter Timeline plugin that stopped working.

I followed all the steps as instructed on the github page. But for some reason when I go to get the pin number, I get an Error message. I have uploaded this plugin to other sites and everything worked fine. I'm not sure what happen.

Has anyone else experienced this, if so what did you do to solve this issue? Here is what the Error Message reads:

```
A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `exp_twitter_settings` (`var`, `var_value`, `site_id`) VALUES ('nsm_twitter', Array, '1')

Filename: third_party/twitter/models/twitter_model.php

Line Number: 103
```

Comment: Have you got NSM Twitter installed as well? It looks like there might be a conflict.

Comment: Yes that NSM Twitter is still installed. I'll uninstall that and get back to you on the results.

Comment: @Dylan I removed that NSM Twitter plugin and everything worked out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this, guys. I've got a pull request in for an update to the Click Rain add-on--once it's been reviewed this bug should be squashed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if there's a conflict between the Click Rain Twitter and NSM Twitter modules. I think that they are both trying to use the 'exp_twitter_settings' table for their settings. You could try uninstalling the NSM Twitter module for the moment and then get in contact with both authors to let them know.

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict between the [Click Rain Twitter](https://github.com/click-rain/EE_Twitter) and NSM Twitter modules. As of this morning, the Click Rain Twitter module is [now changed](https://github.com/click-rain/EE_Twitter/pull/21) to use the table `exp_cr_twitter_settings` rather than `exp_twitter_settings`, avoiding the conflict.

*Disclosure: I work for [Click Rain](http://clickrain.com) and help maintain the plugin when possible.*